# Add text at the top of the counter

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to add text to my counter **before** the counter starts working. Can I add it using my current code ? In this piece of code everything is controlled by JavaScript. I couldn't customize that :(.

Any help would be appreciated !

HTML :

```
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

JS :

```
let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    degree = 0,
    countD = ['3', '2', '1', "Go!"],
    count = 0;

canvas.height = 344;
canvas.width = 344;

let c = canvas.getContext('2d');
let degreeToRadian = function(degree){
  return (degree*22)/(180*7);
}

let animate = function(){
  if(count<3){
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  }
  c.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  c.beginPath();
  /* border alignment*/
  c.arc(170, 170, 150, degreeToRadian(-90), degreeToRadian(degree));
  c.shadowBlur = 15;
  c.shadowColor = "red";
  c.strokeStyle="white";
  c.lineWidth = 10;
  c.stroke();


  c.beginPath();
  /* Text alignment */
  c.strokeText(countD[count], 170, 215);
  c.lineWidth = 0;
  c.font = "120px NeonTubes2Regular";
  c.textAlign = "center";
  c.stroke();

  degree+=4;
  if(degree === 360){
    degree = 0;
    count++;
  }
} animate();
```

Comment: can you share your html code?

Comment: Hi Punitha Subramani Yoganyaa S, html is just this    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>

Comment: Any solution..?

Comment: The code is breaking for me. If can, please add it in fiddle.

Comment: No actually, we need add text ( Eg: dummy text ) just before the counter appear. The text should show then have to fadeout then only counter show and start working.

Comment: Can you try this link? http://dev.netbramha.in/projects/counter/practice%20shot%20try.html

Comment: Hey Punitha.............???

Comment: try and let me know
let c = canvas.getContext('2d');
c.fillText("test data....",10,50);

Comment: I have added in Jfidle. https://jsfiddle.net/Coder95/92Lf3vcp/

Comment: Can you please check now?

Comment: Yeah, it is working!

Comment: Let me add the in aswer, take and run from your end

Comment: its not working. Where should I add the line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    degree = 0,
    countD = ['3', '2', '1', "Go!"],
    count = 0;

canvas.height = 344;
canvas.width = 344;

let c = canvas.getContext('2d');
let degreeToRadian = function(degree){
  return (degree*22)/(180*7);
}

let animate = function(){
  if(count<3){
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  }
  c.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  c.beginPath();
  /* border alignment*/
  c.arc(170, 170, 150, degreeToRadian(-90), degreeToRadian(degree));
  c.shadowBlur = 15;
  c.shadowColor = "red";
  c.strokeStyle="white";
  c.lineWidth = 10;
  c.stroke();


  c.beginPath();
  /* Text alignment */
  c.strokeText(countD[count], 170, 215);
  c.lineWidth = 0;
  c.font = "120px NeonTubes2Regular";
  c.textAlign = "center";
  c.fillText("test data....",10,50);
  c.stroke();

  degree+=4;
  if(degree === 360){
    degree = 0;
    count++;
  }
}
  animate();
```

Comment: Yeah its working. Actually it should appear and disappear before the counter starts working.